# HTML Emailer : Background image is not appearing proper from the mail

Tags: html

I am creating HTML Emailer.

When I see in the browser by clicking in the mail then background is not appearing proper.

```html
<table>
<tr>
        <td align="middle" style="background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/ixr4wNC.jpg); background-size: cover; height: 740px; ">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style=" margin: 0 auto !important; padding: 0px; width:600px !important; line-height: 100% !important; border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" >
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" align="center">
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt; font-family: SansSerif; ">
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="height: 450px; visibility: hidden;">text</td>
                            </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding-top: 10px; font-size: 12px; padding-left: 20px;">
                                        
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: I would suspect it would be better to attach the background image to the email rather than do a remote call to the URL. The email agent will still need to load the same amount of data either way.

Comment: I also suspect that `background-size:cover/contain` properties are not at all standard amongst email agents....

Comment: actually there are 3 contents that is to be clickable.. a youtube link and download buttons. but i m facing issue with background-image. and the link has to be dynamic. that's why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently google's parser doesn't like a standalone `background-size` declaration so it must be included as shorthand or it will be stripped out.

```
background: url('image.gif') no-repeat center center / 100%;
```

Comment: That desn't tell me anything useful. What's improper about it?

Comment: can you you come in teamviwer? so that i can show you the result.

Comment: i guess, pull me in

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132634/discussion-between-rishi-and-serg-chernata).